# bash - Unexcepted Token

Tags: bash, scripts, sed, wget

I'm writing a bash script to automatize my downloading process. In a section, it gaves a error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `newURL=$(echo $URL | sed 's/&:/$index/')'

That section of code is here:

```
# Downloading the pdf's.
for index in {$startedNumber..$endedNumber} do
    newURL=$(echo $URL | sed 's/&:/$index/')
    wget $newURL
done
```

This section handles a URL like "http://xxxx.com/xxx/yyy/zzz&:.pdf" and find "&:" part. When it finds that, it will change it to $index. So that I can download these lines:
http://xxxx.com/xxx/yyy/zzz1.pdf
http://xxxx.com/xxx/yyy/zzz2.pdf
http://xxxx.com/xxx/yyy/zzz3.pdf
http://xxxx.com/xxx/yyy/zzz4.pdf (... and goes on until de $endedNumber)

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here in addition to those addressed in current answers

1. bash doesn't (directly) support the use of shell variables inside a brace expansion. See for example

   - [Can I use variables inside {} expansion without `eval`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117144/can-i-use-variables-inside-expansion-without-eval)
2. `$index` wont get expanded because your sed expression is single-quoted. See for example

   - [How can I use variables in the LHS and RHS of a sed substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-in-the-lhs-and-rhs-of-a-sed-substitution)
3. avoid using ALL-CAPS variables names and don't forget to double-quote variable expansions

   - [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
   - [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts)

In fact you don't need `sed` at all since the shell itself can do simple search and replace on variables directly. So for example

```
startedNumber=3; endedNumber=7

url="http://foo&:bar"

for index in $(seq $startedNumber $endedNumber); do 
  echo wget "${url/&:/$index}"
done
wget http://foo3bar
wget http://foo4bar
wget http://foo5bar
wget http://foo6bar
wget http://foo7bar
```

(remove the `echo` for your real case).

Answer (score 1):

The `do` keyword should either be on a new line or after a `;`.

General rule of thumb from personal experience, when an error is reported as being near an unexpected token, always look at the code before it (not just in bash)